# Image as a label for pixel wise classification using lmdb

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I was having a problem for configuring [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) to do pixel wise segmentation. However, after research, I found that you can create another [Imdb](http://www.imdb.com/) database for labels. I have done that, but I don't know how to link the data and label databases in the training `prototxt` file. Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Included links of referred providers and fixed some grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are aiming for pixel-wise segmentation I'm gonna call what you call labels as ground truths.

The simple solution is - Use two input layers.

Use one input layer to read the image and some fake labels. Use another input layer to read the ground truth and some fake labels. Use the image and ground truth blobs wherever appropriate in your network.

Comment: how will i configure that in the net.prototxt file?, i can't find an example of that

Comment: Take the alexnet prototxt file for example. Instead of one input layer. Put two.